# unreachable statement after finally block

Tags: java, exception

I'm learning about exceptions in Java, and I'm facing a compilation error in this example:

```
public class FinallyExceptionExample {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            System.out.println("1");
            throw new Exception();
        } finally{
            System.out.println("3");
        }
        System.out.println("4");
    }
}
```

The exception is "unreachable statement" for the line:

```
System.out.println("4");
```

I'm wondering why i'm getting this error, normally after finally we continue the execution of the code?

Comment: No, why would code execution continue normally after an uncaught exception?

Comment: Your method throws an exception and doesn't catch it, so anything after the `try/finally` block can't be reached.

Comment: @khelwood but the finally block is executed.

Comment: Yes, but a finally block doesn't catch the exception. It gets run, and then the exception is still uncaught, so the method exits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `finally` statement doesn't catch exceptions thrown in the `try` block. Only `catch` statements can catch exceptions.

Therefore, `System.out.println("4");` is never reached, since the try block always throws an uncaught exception.

Answer (score 1):

you didnt catch your exception. so 1 is printed, the finally block executed and then the exception gets thrown. 4 will never be called

Answer (score 0):

You throw an exception without catching it. This will result in early termination of the code execution and never reach the last line.

Answer (score 0):

From [Oracle documentation](http://The%20finally%20block%20always%20executes%20when%20the%20try%20block%20exits.%20This%20ensures%20that%20the%20finally%20block%20is%20executed%20even%20if%20an%20unexpected%20exception%20occurs.%20But%20finally%20is%20useful%20for%20more%20than%20just%20exception%20handling%20%E2%80%94%20it%20allows%20the%20programmer%20to%20avoid%20having%20cleanup%20code%20accidentally%20bypassed%20by%20a%20return,%20continue,%20or%20break.%20Putting%20cleanup%20code%20in%20a%20finally%20block%20is%20always%20a%20good%20practice,%20even%20when%20no%20exceptions%20are%20anticipated.)

> The **finally** block always executes when the try block exits. This ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected exception occurs. But finally is useful for more than just exception handling — it allows the programmer to avoid having cleanup code accidentally bypassed by a return, continue, or break. Putting cleanup code in a finally block is always a good practice, even when no exceptions are anticipated.

Remember: `finally` does not catch an exception !